# Is it possible to dynamically size buffers when fetching varchar2 column values?

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

Given a table with *FAT* rows of many potentially large strings:

`create table t (s1 varchar2(4000), ..., sN varchar2(4000))`

I know how to fetch these columns using *direct* binds, i.e.

```
std::vector<char> buf1(4000, '\0');
OCIDefineByPos(..., 1, &buf1.front(), sb4(buf1.size()),
               SQLT_CHR, &ind1, &rlen1, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
foreach row {
  std::string actual1(buf1.begin(), buf1.begin() + rlen1);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires knowing a-priori all the columns max-size (a describe could also tell me that, but that's more work), but also forces pre-allocating many large buffers when the data contained in each cell is much smaller in practice.

I've tried using piece-wise fetch, replacing OCI_DEFAULT with OCI_DYNAMIC_FETCH and register my callback using OCIDefineDynamic, and I do get called with OCI_FIRST_PIECE, to provide a buffer dynamically, but here again the provided buffer must be large enough, and OCI does not provide the actual size of the varchar2 column fetched, as one would expect, to be able to size the buffer dynamically just as large as necessary, or just accept the too-short buffer and call me back again with OCI_NEXT_PIECE so I can accumulate the value chunk by chunk.

Right now I systematically get `ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated`

Can anyone provide an example of dynamically allocated fetch buffers please? TIA, --DD

Comment: How have you solved this problem? Do you have an example? I'm faced with the same one. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tried the suggested OCIString route, but couldn't make it work either. Sorry. I have trouble to believe there's no solution to this, but so far nothing. We dynamic bind on selects, so we use a single buffer per-column, and then copy the value into its final destination sized "just right", so at least we pay for the large buffer only once, and many times as we would with array-define.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by fetching `SQLT_VST` instead of `SQLT_CHR` and relying on [OCIString](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci11oty.htm#421613). The memory allocation is automatically managed inside OCI, and you actually get a pointer to it. Then  you can get the size of the actual value with `OCIStringSize()` and `malloc()` that and copy it, or just use it as a regular `char*` pointer via `OCIStringPtr()`.